# javascript validate form input with numbers, alphabets and a special character in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, regex

The input I want the user to key in is in either of these formats:

> D345/98765/2030
>   D345s/98765/2030

Let me try to explain it. It should start with:

- one letter (uppercase or lowercase)
- followed by a maximum of 3 numbers
- then another OPTIONAL single letter which can be either uppercase or lowercase
- then a forward slash followed by a maximum of five numbers
- then another forward slash followed by exactly 4 numbers.

Just to mention, spaces are not allowed. I'm new to this validation and any assistance would be highly appreciated. I've checked existing questions and none answers this satisfactorily. Kindly assist me with the JavaScript code, Here is my input code:

```
<div class='control-group'>
    <!-- Reference-->
    <div class='controls'>
        <input required type='text' autocomplete='off' id='reference' name='reference' placeholder='Enter your reference number'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use one of these sites to help you build and test your regex https://regex101.com/ https://regexr.com/

Comment: Maybe this can help you `^[a-zA-Z]\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]?\/\d{1,5}\/\d{4}$`

Comment: Please ensure the updated version of your question still respects the original format. Also, when you mentioned *maximum*, I'm assuming minimum is 0?

Comment: Yeah it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ygatAP/1) is what you are looking for:

`^[a-zA-Z]\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]?\/\d{1,5}\/\d{4}$`

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- One letter(case insensitive) `[a-zA-Z]`
- Up to 3 numbers `\d{1,3}`
- Optional single letter (case insensitive) `[a-zA-Z]?`
- Forward slash `\/`
- Up to five numbers `\d{1,5}`
- Forward slash `\/`
- Exactly 4 numbers `\d{4`
- to the end of the string `$`

**Edit**: based on your question about the "Invalid reference number" alert

You could implement your code like this:

```
function ValidateInput() {
    var textBoxvalue = document.getElementById('reference').value;
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]?\/\d{1,5}\/\d{4}$/;
    if (pattern.test(textBoxvalue)) {
        alert('Good to go');
    }
    else {
        alert('Invalid reference number');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is correct assuming when the OP specified *maximum*, they also implied a minimum of 1 character? This respects the OP's formatting specifications.